# Price Issue for Multi-currency

Tags: magento, currency, magento-1.5

I am facing Currency Changing problem for Multiple currency store in magento. i am making a custom magento theme. in price display check i have written code like this but unfortunately 
currency changing is not working.

```
            <div class="price_list">
                            <p>List Price: <?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();?><?php echo number_format($price,2); ?></p>
                            <p><span>Sale Price: <?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();?><?php echo number_format($specialprice,2); ?></span></p>
                        </div>
```

So i need a solution how can i call these price function to my theme as if multi-currency will work properly

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Mage::helper('core')->currency($value)` that by default get the current store and format the value.